# using JQ to recursively replace a value for a specific name on a file

Tags: shell, jq

I am trying to use **JQ** to recursively  replace a value for a specific name on a file,
I used JQ before to replaces values in a file but the current JSON file I have is not something that I am familiar with so I couldn't get it to work.

What I need is to replace the value

> ("Value": "tpcohen45342@gmail.com")

of every email with a dummy email (let's say *"yahoo@gmail.com"*),
on a JSON file looks like that:

```
[{
        "Username": "a+123@zzz.com",
        "Attributes": [{
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "fa97fbc3-5916-4eca-bfed-e4b3468ad51c"
        }, {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        }, {
            "Name": "name",
            "Value": "NA reg"
        }, {
            "Name": "preferred_username",
            "Value": "18796"
        }, {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "a+123@zzz.com"
        }],
        "UserCreateDate": "2020-07-01T09:23:33.586Z",
        "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-07-01T09:23:33.586Z",
        "Enabled": true,
        "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
    },
    {
        "Username": "thos.wsdalkiers@restorem.com",
        "Attributes": [{
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "5fd921e4-e3d8-4b34-b742-41006159e6b2"
        }, {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        }, {
            "Name": "name",
            "Value": "Thomas Walkiers (prod)"
        }, {
            "Name": "preferred_username",
            "Value": "8375"
        }, {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "thos.wsdalkiers@restorem.com"
        }],
        "UserCreateDate": "2020-07-10T15:14:39.724Z",
        "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-07-10T15:14:39.724Z",
        "Enabled": true,
        "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
    },
    {
        "Username": "tpcohen4551@gmail.com",
        "Attributes": [{
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "5d6ff6d2-0ab8-4903-9a87-18f0c69c2282"
        }, {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        }, {
            "Name": "name",
            "Value": "Tal tal"
        }, {
            "Name": "preferred_username",
            "Value": "24982"
        }, {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "tpcohen4551@gmail.com"
        }],
        "UserCreateDate": "2020-10-04T12:54:09.688Z",
        "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-11-23T14:03:06.034Z",
        "Enabled": true,
        "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
    },
    {
        "Username": "tpcohen45342@gmail.com",
        "Attributes": [{
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "216ec955-004f-4b5e-b978-0386f22b0029"
        }, {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        }, {
            "Name": "name",
            "Value": "Tal Yartal"
        }, {
            "Name": "preferred_username",
            "Value": "27550"
        }, {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "tpcohen45342@gmail.com"
        }],
        "UserCreateDate": "2020-11-26T07:25:11.645Z",
        "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-11-26T07:27:59.648Z",
        "Enabled": true,
        "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
    },
    {
        "Username": "user.rndmgt@restorem.com",
        "Attributes": [{
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "d0b62a0d-2bc7-447a-af06-bebd68544307"
        }, {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        }, {
            "Name": "name",
            "Value": "c 1"
        }, {
            "Name": "preferred_username",
            "Value": "13109"
        }, {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "user.rndmgt@restorem.com"
        }],
        "UserCreateDate": "2020-06-22T15:59:50.944Z",
        "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-06-22T15:59:50.944Z",
        "Enabled": true,
        "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
    }
]
```

So I will get a result of something looking like that:

```
[{

    "Username": "user.rndmgt@restorem.com",
    "Attributes": [{
        "Name": "sub",
        "Value": "d0b62a0d-2bc7-447a-af06-bebd68544307"
    }, {
        "Name": "email_verified",
        "Value": "true"
    }, {
        "Name": "name",
        "Value": "c 1"
    }, {
        "Name": "preferred_username",
        "Value": "13109"
    }, {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "yahoo@gmail.com"
    }],
    "UserCreateDate": "2020-06-22T15:59:50.944Z",
    "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-06-22T15:59:50.944Z",
    "Enabled": true,
    "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
}]
```

I appreciate the help, and sorry for not showing what I've tried so far I mainly got JQ index errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
jq 'map(.Attributes |= map(if .Name == "email" then 
                             .Value = "yahoo@gmail.com"
                           else 
                              .
                           end))' input.json
```

Comment: looking great, how do I save  this on the file?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan Normal shell redirection to a temp file and copying over. Or maybe with `sponge` if you have that installed.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use JQ to recursively replace a value for a specific name on a file

If the emphasis is on *recursively*, you might wish to consider using `walk`:

```
walk(if type == "object"
     and .Name == "Email" 
     and .Value == "tpcohen45342@gmail.com"
     then .Value = "yahoo@gmail.com" else . end)
```